# How to write/read multiple times to a pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

I'm trying to make two child processes communicate with each other via pipe.First child have to write data 1 and data 2, and then second child writes data 3 and data 4. Then childrens read each other data and print them. This is the code that i have so far. It only displays the first messages children sends to each other and than it hangs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(void) {

    pid_t child_a, child_b;
    int pipe_a[2],pipe_b[2];
    char mesazhi1[] = "First message";
    char mesazhi2[] = "Second message";

    char buf[50];

    int first_pipe = pipe(pipe_a);
    int second_pipe = pipe(pipe_b);

    if(first_pipe == -1 || second_pipe == -1 ){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    child_a = fork();

    if (child_a == 0) {
        /* Child A code */

        printf("%s\n","the first child is writing to pipe a" );
        write(pipe_a[1],mesazhi1, sizeof(mesazhi1));
        write(pipe_a[1],mesazhi2,sizeof(mesazhi2));

        while( read(pipe_b[0],buf,sizeof(buf) + sizeof(buf) ) > 0 ){
              printf("Reading from buffer for child 1 gives:  %s \n",buf);
        }

    } else {
        child_b = fork();

        if (child_b == 0) {
            /* Child B code */

            printf("%s\n","the second child is writing to pipe b" );
            write(pipe_b[1],mesazhi2,sizeof(mesazhi2));



            while( read(pipe_a[0],buf,sizeof(buf) +sizeof(buf) ) > 0 ){
                printf("Reading from buffer for child 2 gives: %s \n",buf);
            }
            write(pipe_b[1],mesazhi1,sizeof(mesazhi1));



            printf("%s\n","the second child reads data from pipe a" );


        } else {
            /* Parent Code */

            int returnStatusA,returnStatusB;    
            waitpid(child_a, &returnStatusA, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.
            waitpid(child_b, &returnStatusB, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.


            if (returnStatusA == 0 && returnStatusB == 0)  // Verify child process terminated without error.  
            {
               printf("%s\n", "The child processes terminated normally.\n"); 
            }

            if (returnStatusA == 1 && returnStatusB == 1)      
            {
               printf("%s\n", "The child processes terminated with an error!. \n" );    
            }



            printf("%s\n","The parent terminates two childs");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't say I have done a detailed inspection, but try `close()` on the pipe file descriptors when you are done writing and reading.  It could be a buffering issue.

Comment: Ah, it hangs.  You really should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @cdarke , I edited my question so it says that it hangs. Is it possible to write multiple datas in a pipe and then read them?

Comment: Both processes are trying to read at the same time.

Comment: It is possible to have multiple processes writing and reading.. but you have to have a very clear idea in your code as to who is writing and who is reading at any given moment.  If you call read() on a pipe in 'A', it will block in the call to read() and do nothing else until 'B' writes to the pipe and gives 'A' some data to read.  And vice versa.  In a lot of programs this is enough.  If you are in the situation where you have no idea when data will arrive and need to do something while you are waiting, you can use select() to check for the presence of data on the pipe before you read().

Comment: @little_birdie I have two child processes and also two pipes, child A writes in pipe A also child B writes in pipe B, both of them read each other data and print them out. The code works when I'm writing just on string in each pipe but as soon as I try to write two strings than it just hangs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code causes a **deadlock**.

You're using `read()` function in a wrong way. `read(pipe_a[0],buf,sizeof(buf) +sizeof(buf) )`

You expect twice of size of your buffer and want to put that amount of bytes in your buffer. So `read` in child A waits for `pipe_b` and vice versa. Therefore child B can't write to `pipe_b` because it's waiting.Similarly, child A can't write in `pipe_a` because it's waiting.

Additionally, Your code is not same as the scenario you explained in your question. In child B you are writing after reading.

And finally use `strlen()` for calculating length of strings instead of `sizeof`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    pid_t child_a, child_b;
    int pipe_a[2],pipe_b[2];
    char mesazhi1[] = "First message";
    char mesazhi2[] = "Second message";

    char buf[50];

    int first_pipe = pipe(pipe_a);
    int second_pipe = pipe(pipe_b);

    if(first_pipe == -1 || second_pipe == -1 ){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    child_a = fork();

    if (child_a == 0) {
        /* Child A code */

        printf("%s\n","the first child is writing to pipe a" );
        write(pipe_a[1],mesazhi1, strlen(mesazhi1) + 1);
        write(pipe_a[1],mesazhi2, strlen(mesazhi2) + 1);

        read(pipe_b[0], buf, strlen(mesazhi1) + 1);
        printf("Reading from buffer for child 1 gives:  %s \n",buf);        
        read(pipe_b[0], buf, strlen(mesazhi2) + 1);
        printf("Reading from buffer for child 1 gives:  %s \n",buf);        

    } else {
        child_b = fork();

        if (child_b == 0) {
            /* Child B code */

            printf("%s\n","the second child is writing to pipe b" );


            read(pipe_a[0],buf, strlen(mesazhi1) + 1);
            printf("Reading from buffer for child 2 gives:  %s \n",buf);            
            read(pipe_a[0],buf, strlen(mesazhi2) + 1);
            printf("Reading from buffer for child 2 gives:  %s \n",buf);            

            write(pipe_b[1],mesazhi1, strlen(mesazhi1) + 1);
            write(pipe_b[1],mesazhi2, strlen(mesazhi2) + 1);


            printf("%s\n","the second child reads data from pipe a" );


        } else {
            /* Parent Code */

            int returnStatusA,returnStatusB;    
            waitpid(child_a, &returnStatusA, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.
            waitpid(child_b, &returnStatusB, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.


            if (returnStatusA == 0 && returnStatusB == 0)  // Verify child process terminated without error.  
            {
               printf("%s\n", "The child processes terminated normally.\n"); 
            }

            if (returnStatusA == 1 && returnStatusB == 1)      
            {
               printf("%s\n", "The child processes terminated with an error!. \n" );    
            }



            printf("%s\n","The parent terminates two childs");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i did the change on function read, also I've put my write function call in child B before reading, and it stills hangs.I think the problem is at reading cause when I put breaks in while loops the program finishes executing

Comment: I changed your code a little and added that to my answer. It works.